# First minus last element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written some code that prints 25 random numbers between 3 and 7 and puts them into an array, and then its reverse array. How would I now subtract the first number in the array minus the last number in the array? Here is my code so far. I have the function call and prototype made; just not sure what to put in the definition exactly:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void showArray ( int a[ ], int size ); // shows the array in the format "int a [ ] = { 3, 7, 4, ... ,5, 6, 3, 4, 7 } "
void showBeforeIndex( int a [ ], int size, int index); // shows all array values before a specified index
int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size );
// **************************************************************************************************************************************
int main ()
{
// Array and reverse array
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int i=0;
    const int SIZE = 25;
    int randvalue[SIZE];


    cout << "Making an array of 25 random integers from 3 to 7!" << endl;

    for(; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    randvalue[i] = rand () % 5 + 3; // random number between 3 to 7
    }
    cout << "Original array a [ ] = {";
    showArray(randvalue, SIZE);
    cout << "}" << endl;

    int j = SIZE-1;
    i = 0;

    while( i <= j)
    {
        swap(randvalue[i], randvalue[j]);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    cout << "Reversed array a [ ] = {";
    showArray(randvalue, SIZE);
    cout << "}" << endl;
// *******************************************************************************************************
// Function call for FIRST - LAST
    int returnFirstLast = firstMinusLast (randvalue, 25);
    cout << "The difference between the first and and last array elements is " << returnFirstLast << endl;
//********************************************************************************************************


    return 0;
}

// Function definition for ARRAY
void showArray ( int a[ ], int size )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << a[i];
}


// Function definition for FIRST - LAST
int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size )
{
    int fml;




    return fml;
}
```

Comment: Why not fml=a[0]-a[size-1]?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you already have the size of the array, and you know the array is fully populated:

```
    int firstMinusLast ( int a[ ], int size ){
         return a[0] - a[size - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++ arrays are indexed beginning with 0. So the first element is at index 0. Given that the first element of an array is at index 0, then the last element of an array is at an index equal to the size of the array minus 1. So as code:

The first element is `a[0]`

The last element is `a[SIZE - 1]`

So to get their difference:`fml` you simply write: `fml = a[0] - a[SIZE - 1]`

This seems pretty simple for a function so perhaps you are expecting something bigger or different.

Do you need the absolute value of the difference? The magnitude of change without the sign? If so, just use the absolute value function.

`fml = abs(a[0] - a[SIZE-1]);`

If you meant to say that you want first minus last before the reverse, then simply do this:

`fml = a[SIZE-1] - a[0];`

If it needs the `abs` then it doesn't matter which way you do the subtract.